# why the admin needs to log in again after reloading the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create a simple MERN stack blog app. In this blog app, only the admin can create, delete and edit any blog post. The users can just view the blog post.

Those functionalities work. When a user logs in, he can't view the `add-new-post` and `blog/edit/:blogPostId` pages. When an admin with logs in, he can view the `/add-new-post` and `blog/edit/:blogPostId` routes.  But when I reload the page or open a new tab, I need to log in again to create, edit and delete the blog post.

I'm using jwt-token to authenticate and authorize users and admins. The backend for the app is doing ok. I think the problem is in the frontend section. If further code is needed, I'll provide it.

I just need some way to keep the admin or the user logged in so that they don't need to log in every time they reload the page.

`App.js`

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />

        <Route index element={<Home />} />

        <Route path="blog" element={<PostsList />} />

        <Route path="blog/:blogPostId" element={<SinglePostPage />} />

        <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
          <Route path="add-new-post" element={<AddPostForm />} />
          <Route path="blog/edit/:blogPostId" element={<EditPostForm />} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="*" element={<div>Error 404</div>} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

`Login.js`

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setCredentials } from "./authSlice";
import { useLoginMutation } from "./authApiSlice";

export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [login] = useLoginMutation();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { accessToken } = await login({ email, password }).unwrap();
      dispatch(setCredentials({ accessToken }));
      setEmailAndPasswordInputToEmptyStringThenNavigateToHomePage();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('login page: ', err);
    }
  };

  const content = (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" value={email} onChange={() => setEmail(e.target.value)} />

        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" onChange={() => setPassword(e.target.value)} value={password} />

        <button>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );

  return content;
};
```

`authSlice.js`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: { token: null },
  reducers: {
    setCredentials: (state, action) => {
      const { accessToken } = action.payload;
      state.token = accessToken;
    },
    logOut: (state, action) => {
      state.token = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { setCredentials, logOut } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;

export const selectCurrentToken = (state) => state.auth.token;
```

`authApiSlice.js`

```
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";
import { logOut, setCredentials } from "./authSlice";

export const authApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (credentials) => ({
        url: "/auth/login",
        method: "POST",
        body: { ...credentials },
      }),
    }),

    sendLogout: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/auth/logout",
        method: "POST",
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          console.log(data);
          dispatch(logOut());
          setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState());
          }, 1000);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      },
    }),
     
    refresh: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/auth/refresh",
        method: "GET",
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          console.log(data);
          const { accessToken } = data;
          dispatch(setCredentials({ accessToken }));
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useLoginMutation, useSendLogoutMutation, useRefreshMutation } =
  authApiSlice;
```

`app/api/apiSlice.js`

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { setCredentials } from "../../features/auth/authSlice";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:3500",
  credentials: "include",
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = getState().auth.token;

    if (token) {
      headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    }

    return headers;
  },
});

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

  if (result?.error?.status === 403) {
    console.log("sending refresh token");

    const refreshResult = await baseQuery("/auth/refresh", api, extraOptions);

    if (refreshResult?.data) {
      api.dispatch(setCredentials({ ...refreshResult.data }));

      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    } else {
      if (refreshResult?.error?.status === 403) {
        refreshResult.error.data.message = "Your login has expired";
      }
      return refreshResult;
    }
  }

  return result;
};

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  tagTypes: ["Post", "User"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});
```

Comment: You never save the information in `localStorage` or `cookies`. All js variables are cleared after refresh

Answer (score 1):

Redux is an in-memory storage. Each reload, initialises the application, and in turn the Redux store.

Simply said:

**Browser reload = Setting redux store to empty.**

So you need a way to persist the access_token in between reloads. For that, you can use browser storage mechanisms like localStorage or sessionStorage.

Comment: to attach the data to redux store, use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) over redux which will persist the data for you